# How do I cancel firing an arrow?

Tags: cadence-of-hyrule

Sometimes during battle, I’ll hit the button to draw my bow and the enemy will dodge out of my line of fire. This leaves me unable to move until I shoot an arrow.

Is it possible to cancel firing my bow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it possible to cancel firing my bow?

Well, somewhat: you can still enter the pause menu, save & quit. That way, you won't use the arrow. However, that's only a trick answer, so the real answer is **no**.*

---

<sup>* I tried almost every combination of items except for the Rito Feather, because it didn't spawn in my almost-complete run save game. It might be possible to cancel the bow with the Feather, but I doubt that.</sup>